# Org: how to insert a skeleton with hierarchial list at the right level?

Tags: org-mode

I have made a hierarchial list of headlines in skeleton, like this:

```
(define-skeleton myskel-list
"Insert claim block"  nil
"* Heading a\n"
"** Heading aa\n"
"* Heading b\n"
"** Heading bb\n"
)
```

I want to insert this skeleton inside a an allready existing headline hierarchy in such av way that the skeleton headings becomes subheadings at the pont I insert it.

Hence if my existing headline hierarchy look like this

```
* My book
** Chapter 1
```

and I insert my skeleton under "Chapter 1" the result should look like this

```
* My book
** Chapter 1
*** headline a\n
**** headline aa\n
*** headline b\n
**** headline bb\n
```

Hence, the levels in the skeleton (level 1 and 2) must be added the level of the insert point, in this case level 2, so that "heading a" ends on level 1+2=3, "heading aa" ends up at level 2+2=4, and so on.

So, how can I make a skeleton that add its heading levels to the heading level at the point I insert it? What must be changed in my skeleton code to accomplish this?

Thanks for any suggestings and help.

Comment: I don't know how to do that but you can easily `org-demote-subtree` (`M-S-<right>`) your skeleton once inserted.

Answer (score 2):

I use this setting to make yasnippet snippets behave like `org-paste-subtree`.

```
(defun my--yas-expand-org-snippet (orig content &optional start end expand-env)
;;  (require 'cl)
  (if (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
    (flet ((insert (content)
                   (org-paste-subtree nil content)))
      (funcall orig content start end expand-env))
    (funcall orig content start end expand-env)
    )
  )
(advice-add 'yas-expand-snippet :around 'my--yas-expand-org-snippet)
```